# A *.exe app made in java, to execute it needs to have java installed?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, libgdx, exe

A *.exe app made in java, to execute it needs to have java installed?

I transformed a *.jar into an *.exe and I don't know if it can run well in *.exe mode.

Comment: How did you turn the .jar into the .exe?

Comment: Did you try it on a system without Java installed?

Comment: Of course it will need Java (JRE). Unless there is some way to pack it into that .exe file.

Comment: [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) allows packaging a jre along the jar. But why?

Comment: @Dawnkeeper it's not as uncommon as you would think. Sometimes it's more convenient to package the JRE into the app installer/executable to help out your users and/or in environments where installing Java is not allowed. Or if your program requires a specific version of a JRE (say Java7 but 6 is the system installed version, etc). Eliminates an entire class of errors such as "JAVA_HOME Not Set", etc. It doesn't bloat the executable that much either since both install4j and exec4j strip things out of the JRE directory like docs etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally yes you will need to have java installed.

It depends on the packager, Java knows nothing about .exes, so you used some external tool to package your exe as a jar.  That tool COULD put the entire JVM into the .exe, but it's very unlikely.

Some also recompile it to native code (Jikes if it's still around is one) but that might still need access to jave install so it can get at the libraries... but it may also be able to re-compile the required libraries and include them in the exe

In other words, it all depends on the packager, look at it's documentation.

Answer (score -1):

You will need something like `exec4j`:

https://www.ej-technologies.com/download/exe4j/files

From their website:

> exe4j is a Windows launcher generator.
>
> exe4j is useful if you want to create a Java launcher without an installer.

This will package your java project/JAR into a Windows .EXE file, and optionally bundle a JRE into the package so that your users are not required to have a local JRE already installed.

A JRE needs to be available at runtime for your application to work, so you can either bundle it into your executable, or have the user install one onto their system.

If your project is OpenSource, and has a website, generally EJ Technologies (the company behind exec4j, install4j, jProfiler, and other great Java technologies) will provide you with a free OpenSource License.

Comment: anyone care to explain the downvotes? this is a preferred solution to the OP's situation.

Comment: He already has an exe file. He wants to know whether he needs to install Java to run it on another computer.

Comment: @Stendika it really sounds like he just renamed the .jar --> .exe, which won't work, obviously.

Comment: Yes, it sounds like that, but we don't _know_ that for a fact. I'm giving him the benefit of the doubt here.

Comment: @Stendika well in either case, using `exec4j` is a perfectly acceptable solution (and a rather easy one I might add). I realize you didn't downvote, but it's still bothersome that others did even though this provides a solution for the OP in both cases.

Comment: @Stendika Stackoverflow is made for developers and for developers SnakeDocs answer seems to be rigth. He tells the OP, how he can package the JRE into a .exe. If he only got a .exe from somewhere else and is not able to execute it, SO is not the rigth place to ask.

Comment: @Springrbua If he has an exe file that he developed, and is trying to figure out how to distribute it (i.e. does he need to package the JRE along with it), I don't see why this would not be the right place to ask.

Comment: @Stendika as i said, if he developed the .exe SO is the rigth place to ask and in this case this answer is absolutely right. So my point is, that to me, this answer is helpful, if the OP is a developer and so it does not diserve the downvotes.